# A-frame : How to replay 3DoF controllers on desktop?

Tags: aframe

My goal is to record motion with the oculus go and replay this recording on a desktop computer. Currently I can record, save the recording and replay the recording on the oculus go itself. However when I wish to replay on the computer nothings happens because A-frame is clever enough to see there is no controller connected:

*"The controller components following are only activated if they detect the controller is found and seen as connected in the Gamepad API."* (Aframe.io)

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: HI Erik, i'm afraid I can't give an answer but I am curious as to how you are managing to record on the Go, all my attempts have failed.. I just get a black screen when I go into VR mode

Comment: One trick I discovered was opening the inspector programmatically and than clicking the record button.                        var scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
     scene.addEventListener('loaded', function () {
      scene.components.inspector.injectInspector();
     }); Does that help?

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try..

Comment: I don't know how you can record, but if you can save the JSON file, you can transfer it to the computer and plug it into the Inspector to play.

Comment: I record by opening the inspector programmatically, untick the box 'record on button press' and then I can start recording. I can save the *.json, but I cannot replay on the desktop because the (oculus go/ gear vr) controller never shows up on the computer. Is there a way to override this (i.e. to show the controller even if the device is not detected)?